# "No navigation case match for viewId /empForm.xhtml, action #{backingBean.submitForm} and outcome" error

Tags: jsf, navigation

When I click on the command button in a form, whose action is listened by a backing bean, I am getting the desired output i.e the text I wanted to display + which is pre-appended with this message:

```
No navigation case match for viewId /empForm.xhtml, action #{backingBean.submitForm} and outcome.
```

My WEB-INF/lib is empty, as am using Web-logic Server for execution.

Comment: The error is very descriptive, JSF can't find the view `empForm.xhtml`  in the actual path. Make sure the view exists in the same path or provide the path to get there.

Comment: In the same path as? @Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: I have a hello.xhtml, an empForm.xhtml and few more in WebContent.
Bean in src/com/bean/BackingBean.

Comment: Are you sure you're using JSF 2 or JSF 1.2?

Comment: If you are returning `/empForm.xhtml` this means that you should have `empForm.xhtml` directly in you app folder. If you are using maven it is directly in webapp folder, and in the WebContent folder otherwise.

Comment: yes.. It is JSF2.0 and web-logi server. Not using Maven. @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: @partlov not using Maven. Yes, I have it in the WebContent folder

Comment: Then you should show us code for method `submitForm`. It looks like this method returned an empty String.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Am using a different system, bcos of which I couldn't exactly post you the code right now. But, submitForm for sure is not returning null. As posted in the question raised, this particular message is getting prepended to the original output  @partlov

Comment: I didn't tell null, but an empty string. This means `return ""`.

Comment: Sorry. But my reply to the empty string remains the same

Comment: In its actual state, I doubt your question could be answered.

Comment: let me post the scriptlet and the Bean I used.